# Angular Material date picker changes date when changed it manually and click outside the input field or to another field

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using matDatepicker and it works fine, the only problem is when I want to enter the date manually. So my problem isn't the format but it gets the wrong date.
This is the HTML

```
<mat-form-field class="my-date-picker col-md-7">
                                    <input matInput
                                      [matDatepicker]="picker"
                                      [formControl]="startDate"
                                      (dateChange)="onStartDateChange($event)" required data-qa="startDate">
                                      <mat-hint>MM/DD/YYYY</mat-hint>
                                      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                                    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
                                  </mat-form-field>
```

I am debugging and when I enter the date manually, is read wrong, for example I enter 5/24/2022, and even thought I see the value in input field, in the method, at parameter is 3/07/2022.

```
 onStartDateChange(event) {
    if (event == 0) {
        this.startDate = null;
        
    } else {
        this.startDate = new Date(event.value);
  
    }
}
```

Besides this, if it helps this is my **CustomDateAdapter**

```
export class CustomDateAdapter extends NativeDateAdapter {

  // parse the date from input component as it only expect dates in 
  // mm-dd-yyyy format
  parse(value: any): Date | null {
    if ((typeof value === 'string') && (value.indexOf('/') > -1)) {
      const str = value.split('/');

      const year = Number(str[2]);
      const month = Number(str[1]) - 1;
      const date = Number(str[0]);
      
      return new Date(year, month, date);
    }
    const timestamp = typeof value === 'number' ? value : Date.parse(value);
    return isNaN(timestamp) ? null : new Date(timestamp);
  }
  
  getFirstDayOfWeek(): number {
   return 1;
  }
}
```

and beside this at app.module I have:

```
const INTL_DATE_INPUT_FORMAT = {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'numeric',
    day: 'numeric',
    hourCycle: 'h12',
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
  };
  
  const MAT_DATE_FORMATS: NgxMatDateFormats = {
    parse: {
      dateInput: INTL_DATE_INPUT_FORMAT,
    },
    display: {
      dateInput: INTL_DATE_INPUT_FORMAT,
      monthYearLabel: { year: 'numeric', month: 'short' },
      dateA11yLabel: { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' },
      monthYearA11yLabel: { year: 'numeric', month: 'long' },
    },
  };

providers: [
        
        { provide: NGX_MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MAT_DATE_FORMATS },
        {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: CustomDateAdapter },
        
    ]
```

I have seen several other StackOverflow questions similar to this, but there wasn't much feedback if they found a solution or not, as such questions dated like three years ago.

FROM MY TESTING IT SEEMS IT IS A CAUSE

```
 [matDatepicker]="picker"
```

WHICH MEANS THE INPUT IS BEING OVERWRITTEN FROM IT.
BUT THIS IS THE RELATION THAT OPENS THE CALENDAR AND IS NESSACARY SO I CAN'T REMOVE IT , AND I HAVEN'T FOUND SOME ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION